# AndroidAnnotations @REST: The converter class must be a subtype of org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter RestClient.java

Tags: android, rest, android-annotations

I want create a REST client using AndroidAnnotations

When define converters on @Rest annotation, I receive the following compile error:

```
The converter class must be a subtype of org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter RestClient.java
```

I use this libraries:

/libs

```
androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13
jackson-asl-0.9.5
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13
spring-android-auth-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

/compile-libs

```
androidannotations-2.7.1.jar
```

My source is similar to the example [androidannotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API)

```
package com.sinffredy.spring;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.rest.Get;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.rest.Rest;


@Rest(rootUrl = "http://my.url/ajax/services", converters = { MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface RestClient 
{
     @Get("/.do?valor={search}")
     Respuesta getRespuesta(String search);
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The same source in other pc works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!!! Only change my Eclipse. I was using Helios with Android Development Toolkit

Now I dowload [The Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) than includes Eclipse + ADT plugin. Use my old workspace with my proyect and all work fine!!!.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the same issue than [this one](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/611). Sadly I still can't reproduce this bug.

Just to be sure, could you test by adding `spring-android-rest-template` in your annotation processing factory path ?